# What countries in the world have legalized both abortion and cannabis?

Tags: international, abortion, cannabis-legalization

As far as I am aware, [Uruguay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uruguay#Return_to_democracy_(1984%E2%80%93present)) is the only country in the Americas that has legalized both abortion and cannabis:

> Abortion was legalized in 2012, followed by same-sex marriage and cannabis in the following year.

I know of many countries where either abortion or cannabis are legalized, but I'm not aware of other examples where both are.

Are there any other countries in the world where both abortion and cannabis are legalized *on a country level* (ie: not just on some states)?

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't use comments to answer the question. If you would like to answer, please post a proper answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked at Wikipedia's very nice maps about this:

Here is a map about the legality of marijuana. Blue means that it is fully legalized. I am only counting these, based on the specific wording in the question.

[image: Canada, Alaska, Washington state, Oregon, California, Nevada, Colorado, Michigan, DC, Uruguay, South Africa, and Georgia are blue]

The dark blue countries here are ones where abortion is "legal on request".

[image: Canada, most of the United States of America, Cuba, Guyana, Uruguay Denmark, Estonia, Iceland, Latvia, Lithuania, Norway, Sweden, Ireland, Albania, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Croatia, Greece, Italy, Kosovo, Montenegro, Portugal, Serbia, Slovenia, Spain, Macedonia, Austria, Belgium, France, Germany, Luxembourg, Netherlands, Switzerland, Belarus, Bulgaria, Czech Republic, Hungary, Moldova, Romania, Russia, Slovakia, Ukraine, Armenia, Azerbaijan, Bahrain, Cyprus, Georgia, Turkey, Cambodia, Singapore, Vietnam, Kazakhstan, Kyrgyzstan, Nepal, Tajikistan, Turkmenistan, Uzbekistan, China, North Korea, Mongolia, Cape Verde, Sourth Africa, Tunisia, Mozambique, Western Australia, Northwest Territory, Queensland, Victoria, Tasmania]

If I look at the overlap, **abortion is legal on request and recreational marijuana is *legalized* (as opposed to unenforced or decriminalized) in:**

- Canada
- Uruguay
- South Africa (growing and using but not sale)
- Georgia (growing and using but not sale)

Interestingly, these are actually *all* of the countries (that I know of) with nationally legalized recreational marijuana.

<sub>This list originally counted states and territories in the US, but I removed it.</sub>

<sub>Note: there very likely are some islands that I missed in the alt-text list. Sorry if I did—feel free to correct me in the comments! Also, if anyone is reading this in the future and notices that some of these are outdated, please comment and tell me!</sub>

<sub>View the alt text in the source of this answer for a complete list. All information in this is based on Wikipedia's articles on [marijuana laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_cannabis) and [abortion laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abortion_law), along with their articles on [marijuana in the Northern Mariana Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabis_in_the_Northern_Mariana_Islands) and [in Guam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabis_in_Guam).</sub>

Comment: Nice answer! Although I would remove the US from the list as it it not nation wide.

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks! I am adding a note that states are trying to make abortions much harder to get, but most of those states with legal marijuana are controlled by pro-abortion Democrats and thus it is pretty safe there.

Comment: WRT the US, it should be noted that most of the states which have legalized marijuana have done so through the initiative process http://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/initiative-process-101.aspx rather than through the legislature.  At least one (Nevada) has also protected access to abortion via a similar process.

Comment: Thank you @Stormblessed but the question is about countries with *nation wide* laws, not on a state level. The US does not belong in the list.

Comment: @Gabriel I think it might as well be mentioned (as those states’ total population is in the tens of millions), but I’ll remove it.

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica status-completed

Answer (score 5):

Abortion in Canada is legal at all stages of pregnancy, even though provision of services varies from province to province.

> Abortion is the premature ending of a pregnancy. Inducing an abortion
>   was a crime in Canada until 1988, when the Supreme Court of Canada
>   struck down the abortion law as unconstitutional. Since then, abortion
>   has been legal at any stage in a woman's pregnancy, and is publicly
>   funded as a medical procedure under the Canada Health Act.

[The Canadian Encyclopedia: Abortion in Canada](https://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/abortion)

Cannabis in Canada is legal for both recreational and medicinal purposes.

> Cannabis, also known as marijuana (among countless other names), is a
>   psychoactive intoxicant that was banned in Canada from 1923 until
>   medical cannabis became legal in 2001. The consumption and sale of
>   recreational cannabis was legalized and regulated on 17 October 2018,
>   after Parliament passed Bill C-45, the Cannabis Act.

[The Canadian Encyclopedia: Cannabis Legalization in Canada](https://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/marijuana-legalization-in-canada)